# How to remove "upload" button in Drupal 7 webform?

Tags: file, drupal, webforms

i'm tring to remove the "upload" button of file input in webform using AJAX. i just google it and i found modules that remove the "upload" button in admin panel, and i need remove it in webform.

i tried hide the upload button and trigger click event on upload button when file input changed and its not works ( i think becouse the ajax?...)

this what i tried in template.php

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

 if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_20') {   
     $form['submitted']['_cv_file']['#process'] = array('THEME_file_element_process'); // hide upload button in jobs form

  }
}

function THEME_file_element_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);
  $element['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $element;
}
```

By the way, i need the attachment will not be save on database, and will be send to email...

Thanks for all!
Almog.

Comment: How about hiding it with CSS?

Comment: yes i tried to hide this in css but the problem is that drupal webform cant give me submit the form when the upload buttom doesn't clicked to upload the file. the webform look the file input like i dont selected a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try webform hide upload module

URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_hide_upload

Comment: hello,thanks for your answer but i installed this module and its hide my upload button but i still get a validation error for unuploaded file when i submit the form.

Comment: Then you need to check if the field is required or not and also what file type, file size are allowed.

Comment: yes, when i upload same file when the upload button is enabled, the file uploading... and yes this input is required and i tried to do this not required and the file dont uploading

Comment: Strange. Is your tmp directory writable.

Comment: even if i can uplod the file successfully with the upload buttom?

Comment: i need also to send all input from the form to email with the attachment without save the attachment in the database/server.

maybe module like this will help me?  becouse the upload button uploading to dtabase?

Comment: then you need some development to debug what is going after you submit the form.